# Heat of hydrogenation of 1,3-substituted cyclohexanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, cyclohexane

[image]

From these two molecules in question, (C) should be more unstable as it is in a *cis*-configuration. The *t*-butyl and methyl groups being on the same side of the ring would exert a larger steric force on each other as compared to the trans configuration. However, (D) is mentioned as the correct answer.

**How is a *trans*-1,3 disubstituted cyclohexane more unstable than the corresponding *cis*-isomer?** I drew the chair projections of both compounds and the cis one has both groups on the same side, which would cause 1,3-diaxial interaction as mentioned [here](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/ec_tutorials/tutorial15.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Look at that bottom picture and determine whether the methyl group and the protons that are drawn out are *cis* or *trans* (better names might by *syn* or *anti*)?

Comment: If I am not wrong, the groups in the axial projection are _cis_

Comment: If they are so in the axial projection, they are so too in the equatorial one.

Comment: So are the groups in the axial position _cis_? Was my comment right?

Comment: Yes, methyl and the two marked protons are *cis* in *both* the axial and equatorial pictures.

Comment: Well you should draw the substituents in equatorial positions, because they're more stable than in axial positions where there is chance of strong flagpole repulsions with the axial H atoms. in that way in cis(or syn) both of them would be in equatorial positions and are thus more stable than in trans where one is in axial

Comment: To my understanding, OP has thought all cis-isomers, substituents are in axial-positions. That is a wrong assignment.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne That’s where I tried to steer OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as Jan pointed out on the comment, better nomenclature for thes compounds is *syn*- and *anti*- instead of *cis*- and *trans*-, respectively. However, OP is more familiar with *cis*- and *trans*- nomenclature I'd continue it with my answer.

Each substituted cyclohexane ring (*e.g.*, di-substituted ones here) has two chair conformers as depicted in OP's bottom diagram of methylcyclohexane (a mono-substituted one). In one conformer, the methyl group is in *equatorial* position (left hand structure) and the methyl group in the other one is in *axial* position (right hand structure). Because of two 1,3-interactions cost additional approximately $2 \times \pu{3.8 kJ/mol}$ steric strain energy, the predominant conformer is *equatorial* one.

Now, if you put *tert*-butyl group in $\ce{C3}$-*equotorial* position on *equatorial*-methylcyclohexane (left hand structure, *vide supra*), you get *cis*-1,3-substituted compound (C). On the other hand, if you put *tert*-butyl group in $\ce{C3}$-*equatorial* position of *axial*-methylcyclohexane (right hand structure), you get *trans*-1,3-substituted compound (D). Because it is too bulky, the *tert*-butyl group is always in *equotorial* position in cyclohexane ring (1,3-interaction with one hydrogen would cost additional approximately $\pu{11.4 kJ/mol}$ steric strain energy), as depicted in following diagram (The larger the substituent, the more the equatorial substituted conformer will be favored):

[image: t-Bu-Me-Cyclohexanes]

The most predominant *cis*-isomer (C) has both substituents in *equatorial*-positions (the left hand side structure of (C)). Other conformer (get by the ring flip; the right hand side structure of (C)) has both substituents in *axial*-positions. Thus, as a rule of thumb, the conformer with both substituents in equatorial positions is more stable.

On the other hand, the both *trans*-isomers of (D) have one substituent in an *equatorial*-position and the other in an *axial*-position. Yet, the conformer with the *tert*-butyl group in the *equatorial*-position (left hand side structure of (D)) is more stable between two, because *tert*-butyl group is comparatively much larger than methyl group. However, because most predominant *cis*-isomer (C) has both groups in the *equatorial*-positions, it is relatively more stable than (D), which has methyl on *axial*-position, making additional steric strain energy.